# How to get rid of unsharp picture markers?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, markers

I have made a symbol in Adobe Illustrator to use for a custom picture marker. The thing is when I select these markers and put them in my map the get blurry. I have tried several image formats such as .png .jpg .emf and .bmp. But no succes.

I was looking if there is a way to use a .svg file, but with no result.

Comment: I imagine you are using those formats because you don't want a square icon... so you have a transparent background around your irregular shape (this is what is causing the rasterization). You might be better off to build a font and use that. Try importing your svg into something like Glyphter (https://glyphter.com/). When you export or print your map you will need to embed fonts (or something similar).